# Good image clipper for neural network datasets

Tags: neural-network

Im trying to train a Neural Network and preparing data set. What I found is that it will take like hundred years for me to cut positives from images with help of such applications like Gimp or Photoshop. 
Wondering if there is a good simple tool out there?

The requirement is :

1. I can load an image into the application
2. I can select a cutout area in the image of the same ratio (say a square) by 1 ckick
3. I can save the cut out by pressing say Enter
4. Result image will be saved with a name of predefined format like any_image_name_XCOORD_YCOORD_WIDTH_HEIGHT_SIZEOFORIGINALIMAGE.jpg

Where

- **XCOORD** - is the X coord of the cutout in the original image
- **YCOORD** - is the Y coord of the cutout in the original image
- **WIDTH** - is width of the cutout in the original image
- **HEIGHT** - is width of the cutout in the original image
- **SIZEOFORIGINALIMAGE** - size of original image (like 1280x860)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at imageclipper [imageclipper](https://github.com/JoakimSoderberg/imageclipper) but for me it is a little buggy.